# cap deploy:setup hangs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, cap

Im having setup a empty git repo bare on the server side and everything setup.

Cap deploy:setup does this

```
    [109.etc] env RAILS_ENV=production sh -c 'git clone git@109.etc:srv/paintings.git /srv/paintings/current'
 ** [out :: 109.etc] Initialized empty Git repository in /srv/paintings/current/.git/
 ** [out :: 109.etc] The authenticity of host '109.etc (109.etc)' can't be established.
 ** [out :: 109.etc] RSA key fingerprint is e9:af:d6:d3:0e:f5:de:a3:4a:31:6e:8e:4a:c7:b7:ee.
 ** [out :: 109.etc] Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

*When I type yes or y it just "hangs" nothing seem to happen...
* already tried --debug after the cap deploy:setup what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capistrano is essentially non-interactive; if a prompt like this pops up you can't just tell it "yes", unfortunately, since commands you type in aren't sent to the remote host. You'll have to do the "yes"-ing manually.

To get around this problem, add the host's key to the known_hosts file for that user. So, SSH into whatever machine is doing the deploy, su into that user, and try SSHing into `109.etc`. You'll receive the same warning prompt and you'll be able to enter "yes" in, and this time it'll work. Afterwards, `cap deploy` as per normal and you won't receive this message anymore.

Comment: Added like suggested but problem on cap deploy:setup still there, i can just do ssh root@myhost now without a password prompt. The authenticity of host cannot be.. still persist though :(

Comment: Are you deploying from the root user of that machine? You have to SSH into ```109.etc``` from whatever user is actually performing the deploy.

Comment: Fixed it I had the host in my /etc/hosts and used the alias instead of Ip now I have new error The --deployment flag requires a Gemfile.lock. Please make sure you have checked your Gemfile.lock into version control before deploying. I check your answer as accepted one thx a lot for the help this bugged me like 3 days.